# Loading Driver Using OSR Driver Loader Error

Tags: c, wdk, ndis

I have trouble loading my driver using OSR driver loader. I point the path to my driver, register service successfuly, but when I click start service I receive error message "The system cannot find the file specified."

In the concrete, I have tried to make driver from the sample:

[http://www.ndis.com/ndis-ndis6/inspect/packetinspect.htm](http://%20Hi,%20I%20have%20trouble%20loading%20my%20driver%20using%20OSR%20driver%20loader.%20I%20point%20the%20path%20to%20my%20driver,%20register%20service%20successfuly,%20but%20when%20I%20click%20start%20service%20I%20receive%20error%20message%20%22The%20system%20cannot%20find%20the%20file%20specified.%22%20%20In%20the%20concrete,%20I%20have%20tried%20to%20make%20driver%20from%20the%20sample%3a%20%20%20http://www.ndis.com/ndis-ndis6/inspect/packetinspect.htm)

Any ideas please?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a dependent DLL.

Comment: @CareyGregory I found the problem. I cannot load pnp driver using OSR driver loader, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Making and Signing Driver Packages for NDIS Protocol Drivers](http://www.ndis.com/ndis-general/ndisinstall/makeandsigncat.htm)